# Docker doesn't output the logs from a container

Tags: docker, .net-core, webapi

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1.build docker image,and publish it
2.pull image,then run

```
docker run --name myapp -p 30010:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production -v /home/gdll/host:/app/wwwroot/Files -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --restart=always -d hub.tencentyun.com/xxxx/xxxx
```

3.docker logs myapp

### Expected behavior

Output logs.

### Actual behavior

It's nothing!

### Additional information (e.g. issue happens only occasionally)

The docker logs is json-file.Help Me,Please! I have already crazy.

#### The dotnet info of container

Output of  'dotnet --info'

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  157910edee

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

#### The docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster  AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./aspnet-core/src/ api/src/
COPY ./aspnet-core/tools/ api/tools/
RUN dotnet restore ./api/src/MQKJ.RaiseBaby.Web.Host/MQKJ.RaiseBaby.Web.Host.csproj

# copy everything else and build app
RUN dotnet publish api/src/MQKJ.RaiseBaby.Web.Host/MQKJ.RaiseBaby.Web.Host.csproj -c Release -o out

#finally
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
VOLUME ["/app/wwwroot"]
VOLUME ["/app/App_Data"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MQKJ.RaiseBaby.Web.Host.dll"]
```

### Output of `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:08:18 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:10:42 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

### Output of `docker info`

```
Containers: 6
 Running: 6
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 19
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: s54837jakzc0lel3r2rikpkex
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: r35n5ok1e4wfcu3mdo0hv7q4g
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: xxx.xx.x.xx
 Manager Addresses:
  xxx.xx.x.xx:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.701GiB
Name: VM_0_14_centos
ID: WKV7:KHVQ:6BNP:JM3L:EY5V:A4LM:G7SI:CP4R:ACQ7:VLFW:ETOY:QEKK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 https://xxx.mirror.aliyuncs.com/
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: I suggest you to remove the volume sections from your dockerfile

Comment: Ok,Thank you! I had try it.But it don't work?

Comment: no I just suggest that , because there is no need for them see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start the container with `-d`, which means it will run in detached mode. You can either omit this flag, or run `docker logs -f myapp` to see the logs. [See here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) for some more information about this.

Comment: em,I make a mistake. It not the right answer.Maybe the host has some question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If this doesn't solve your problem, please elaborate what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: enen,It still not work in my two host,but it work in my anothor host and my local virtual host.

Comment: If it doesn't work for another Docker container, you should probably open a separate question or edit your original one. What do you mean by "virtual host"? What happens with your not-working container when you type `docker logs -f [this-containers-name]`?

Comment: when I run `docker logs -f xxx` ，the shell is nothing output ,just empty line all the time.

Comment: Ok, reasons I could think of: 1 - Your container doesn't run. Did you check it with `docker ps`? 2 - Your app doesn't output anything - what happens if you run `docker run --rm busybox echo foo` for example, do you see the output? If yes, your application/your specific image is likely to be faulty at some point. Can you run your app outside of Docker and confirm that there is output?

Comment: Thanks a lot.The cause is work flow of tencent hub ,It's can be output log when I build in jenkins,So it is solved.